# Laravel Horizon running but no route (local)

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to add Horizon to my latest laravel app but when i visit my url with the horizon path (https://my-app.com/horizon) I get a 404, `php artisan routes:list` doesn't contain any routes to horizon. I have ran `php artisan route:clear` and no joy either.

I followed the official docs (https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/horizon) So i did the following commands:

```
composer require laravel/horizon
```

```
php artisan horizon:install
```

and edited the config to use redis. I'm using a local environment at the moment so the gate would not be needed (right?) I am also using spatie/permissions so with a permission of `access horizon` i edited the HorizonServiceProvider.php file as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Laravel\Horizon\Horizon;
use Laravel\Horizon\HorizonApplicationServiceProvider;

class HorizonServiceProvider extends HorizonApplicationServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
    }

    /**
     * Register the Horizon gate.
     *
     * This gate determines who can access Horizon in non-local environments.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function gate()
    {
        Gate::define('viewHorizon', function ($user) {
            return $user->can( 'access horizon' );
        });
    }
}
```

This should allow the user if they have the access horizon permission and refuse otherwise (but I'm on local so will run anyway?)

I'm using laravel 9.23 with php8.1 and have redis enabled. I also see that horizon is running `php artisan horizon`and then `php artisan horizon:status` says `Horizon is running.`

Have I missed something? So Horizon is running redis is enabled and set to use the queue, no horizon route in my route list and if i visit the url i obviously get a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

After power down for the weekend and startup this morning Horizon is now working!